# Understanding design patterns

Tags: design-patterns

I read some books and scoured the web about design pattern,but almost all ways of expressing design patterns are the same. They define what is it,draw UML and give an example,but what I want is to suggest me any site or book that writes some bad code and refactor using one of the design patterns?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be on topic for this site. Computational science doesn't mean computer science in general.

Comment: This would probably be considered unwelcome on the computer science stack exchange too; they are more into computer science theory. The software engineering stackexchange would be a better choice.

Comment: Robert C. Martin's "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship" does almost exactly what you want.